# delay switch state on togglebutton click

Tags: android, events, delay, togglebutton

I need to delay the switching of the state of a togglebutton when I click on it. I have to do some operation and than when another event is called the state of the togglebutton have to change. How can I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subclass the `ToggleButton` and override the click handling. Use an `AsyncTask` to accomplish your task and then do the actual toggling by calling `super.performClick()` when you want to actually perform the toggling.

```
public class MyToggleButton extends ToggleButton {

    public MyToggleButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyToggleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyToggleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        // do your thing here

            // only call the below line if you actually want it to happen.
        return super.performClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you give me an example? Thanks a lot!

Comment: How can I link the click on the togglebutton with this class and how can I manage the event that has to change the state of the togglebutton? Thanks!

Comment: I resolved overriding the setOnCheckedChangeListener and set the state to the current state. Thanks anyway!